# Manipulating Primefaces radio buttons in javascript

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to manipulate primefaces radio buttons via Javascript.

For standard radio buttons, I can simply change the `checked` attribute of the input element:

```
jQuery(".myselector input")[0].checked = true
jQuery(".myselector input")[0].checked = false
```

After that, the buttons are back to the initial state (no item is selected).

With primefaces radio buttons, changing the checked attribute seems to have no effect.
I can select a specific radio button by generating a `click` event on the corresponding
label:

```
jQuery(".mygroup-selector label").get(0).click()
```

However, I am looking for a way to restore the initial state, i.e., unselect all
items. How can this be done?

Comment: Try ......... $('#myRadioButton').get(0).checked

Comment: @rags: Does not work: the jQuery object for the radio button does not have a `checked` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(".myselector input").prop('checked', false);
// Note that the pre-jQuery 1.6 idiom was
// $(".myselector input").attr('checked', false);
OR
$(".myselector input").removeAttr("checked");
OR
$(".myselector input").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this that I found was to manipulate the underlying `checked` attribute
and then manually fire a `changed` event. Then the event handler will automatically update the UI classes:

```
$(".myselector input").prop("checked", false)
$(".myselector input").change()
```

However, other change event handlers will run as well, which may have side effects depending on the situation.

Obviously, Primefaces (or whatever js component it uses) should really provide a proper client side API for this...